# Make synchronous call to firestore in Android device

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-instrumentation

I am trying to update a `firestore` document through Android device. The code is part of `instrumented test` to I've to make a synchronous call to `Firestore` to update the document.

```
DocumentReference ref=db.collection("country").document("city")
                        .collection("Delhi").document("LajpatNagar");
Task<Void> temp=ref.update("isPinCodeAdded",true);
        while(!temp.isSuccessful()){    
        }
```

The execution runs in infinite `while loop` and task is never successful. 
So how can I make sync call in `android instrumented tests` to `firestore`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can block the thread and wait for the result of a Firebase task with

```
Tasks.await(YOUR_TASK)
```

In your case, the code would be

```
Task<Void> temp = Tasks.await(ref.update("isPinCodeAdded",true));
```

For more details, refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#await(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3CTResult%3E)).

Keep in mind that Android won't let you block the main thread, so don't do this if you're on main thread.

Comment: I know about async call that why I clearly mentioned in the question that I need sync calls. I have already managed the thread since this is being run on instrumented test thread.